# How to get assisted conversions in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, looker-studio

Does anyone know how to extract assisted conversions from google analytics to google data studio? When importing a Google Analytics view I didn't find any related dimensions or metrics.

[My expectation is to have this report in data studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK5IP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ok this data comes from mfc (multy funnel channel). This is an part from Analyics. There have no community plugin for free to get this Data in but you can create your own.

2 options

option 1
With Google analytics api to build your own connector and host it in Google Scripts

option 2
Create an Tabel with the Analytics Plugin for google Sheets and use the sheet as a source in data studio. Its more easy like option 1 but the date is constant wich you have choosen in the chart.

About option 2 you can find some tutorials in the net like
https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2018/07/17/multi-channel-funnels-google-data-studio/
that was the first search result by google